# Replace " by \" inside a string

Tags: string, bash, replace

How can I replace a `"` by `\"` inside a string using bash?

For example:

A txt-File contains text like:

```
Banana "hallo" Apple "hey"
```

This has to be converted into:

```
Banana \"hallo\" Apple \"hey\"
```

I tried

```
a=$(cat test.txt)
b=${a//\"/\"}}
```

But this didn't work.

How does that work?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: e.g. a=$(cat test.txt)  and b=${a//\"/\"}} this does not work of course

Comment: Your question is a bit vague about your requirements.  In general, you might address a problem like this with `sed` or perhaps with `awk`.  There are other possibilities.

Comment: The Problem is, that " is a Special character. So the solution that Julien Lopez proposes, is not possible.

Comment: @AnneK. You were actually very close. But both `\` and `"` need to be escaped if you want a literal `\` or `"`

Answer (score 1):

Use [[ parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
string='Banana "hallo" Apple "hey"'
echo "$string"
Banana "hallo" Apple "hey"
string=${string//\"/\\\"} # Note both '\' need '"' need to be escaped.
echo "$string"
Banana \"hallo\" Apple \"hey\"
```

**A lil explanation**

```
${var/pattern/replacement}
```

replaces *one* occurrence of `pattern` in `var` with `replacement`.

```
${var//pattern/replacement}
```

replaces *all* occurrences of `pattern` in `var` with `replacement`.

If the pattern or replacement contains characters like `"` or `/` with special meaning in shell, they need to be escaped to let shell treat them as literals.